# How can I implement swipe-to-delete gesture, exactly as shown in Material Design's documentation?

Tags: java, android, material-design, swipe

I want to implement a swipe-to-delete gesture for my ListView, and Material Design docs show it can be done (see [here](https://material.io/components/lists/#behavior)). Is there a straightforward way of doing this, or am I meant to implement a custom class which extends `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` to add this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you can use another activity to display the information. To perform the transition animation about where it should start, you can do something like this to get the coordinates.

From list view (this is the child view that is called in the adapter, I mean, `containerView`)

```
Rect rect = new Rect();
child.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);
```

The code above will give you the view's position in window, with both left, top, right, bottom coordinates.

While opening the activity, you can create the intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);

// This is the "rect" you got above, the view's coordinates in screen.
intent.setSourceBounds(rect);

// Pass necessary elements through Intent.putExtra()
// These will contain the product's information.
// DO NOT PASS IMAGES HERE, ONLY PASS IMAGE REFERENCES.
intent.putExtra("name", product.name);

// Then start the activity normally.
context.startActivity(intent);
```

This should perform the animation that you see on that link. (If there is an easier way, I don't know what it is, by the way.)